# Impossible to control fan curve/speed

Tags: cpu, fan

For programming purpose, I finally switched to Ubuntu 19.10 on my Aero 15x v8 and could't be happier with the speed, the main problem I encounter is that fans are too loud even when boosting not for long and the workaround right now is to disable the boost and dedicated gpu. I tried the usual solutions with sensors-detect and pwmconfig but it doesn't work (there are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed).

Thanks for your help

Comment: Generally we don't get a lot of success controlling laptop fans.  Check if you have anything fan related in `/proc/acpi/` for acpi control, also run `sensors-detect` for pwm control.

Comment: @rtaft what am I supposed to do in /proc/acpi/ ? I have a deep nested file for the lid in "button" folder and a wakeup file listing device, S-state, status and sysfs node

Comment: I believe if there was fan control abilities over acpi there would be a `/proc/acpi/ibm/fan` folder.  `sensors-detect` searches for pwm based control.

Comment: this is terrible... all I want is that during cpu load spikes that fans don't go full speed